# How to configure to run two Browsers with different IP address?

Tags: windows, browser, ip-address

I have two IP addresses assigned by my ISP, and I want to use both. I'd like to assign each one to a different browser.

Is this possible?  What do I need to do to achieve this?  My OS is Windows server 2003.

Comment: I think simplest solution would be running second browser in VirualPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few options I can think of

1. run a bit of software that allows you to force bind an ip address to an application. I've not tried it myself but [forcebindip](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) may work
2. run a proxy which lets you bind itself to an ip address - I'm not familiar with windows proxies but thats a 'cleaner' approach than the forced binding approach thats mentioned.

Comment: It really works. and binding any process to specific IP address is the best approach. Thank for Answer.

Answer (score 0):

One PC can have multiple IP's and if connection is started from outside this PC will use both IP addresses.

If connections are started from inside, one PC will always use one of its (possible) many IP's. So @week's comment above is correct, to identify to outside world with 2 different IP's in the same time simplest solution is to have 1 real and 1 virtual PC, and you can then in virtual start second browser or just configure a proxy for second browser on your real PC.

Other solution is to have 2 real PC's, where second PC you would use just as proxy for your working PC. Today this is usually overkill, but if you have 2 old PC's with small amount of RAM, this is better (read: faster) solution than having virtual server on a PC with low RAM.

Comment: Its correct but its not good enough because it require more system resources to run another OS inside another.